# Detect Swipe faster than UISwipeGestureRecognizer?

Tags: objective-c

i was wondering how to detect a "swipe" faster than this? I'd like to call a method as soons as the user moves his finger to the left. **Let's call it a "small" swipe gesture.**

This would be the normal/long swipe…

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
recognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
[recognizer release];
[scrollView delaysContentTouches];
```

Comment: Isn't there a danger that you'll get false positives if you try to detect very small movements? - the reason most gestures are large is to ensure that you're picking up something genuinely intended by the user - not just jitter/uneven pressure on the touch surface.

Comment: Sure, but that's okay for my prototype. Best case i can set "the swipe" distance ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Now I build this:

```
#import "UICustomScrollView.h"

@implementation UICustomScrollView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // do stuff
    }
    return self;
}

// Listen for "fast" swipe
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGPoint prevLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self];

    if (location.y - prevLocation.y > 0) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"fastSwipe" object:self];
    }    

    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}


@end
```